# How to hold the graphics screen

Tags: python, graphics

```
    from graphics import *
    win = GraphWin()
    p = Point(50, 60)
    p.getX()
    p.getY()
    p.draw(win)
    p2 = Point(140, 100)
    p.draw(win)
```

When I run this the Graphics window comes and goes in a blink. How do I hold the graphics screen in python.

I tried various functions like
win.getMouse()
win.getKey()
But, was not able to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the window is closing right after you execute the script is because you arent calling the main loop function at the end of the script. It's somewhat similar to putting a print statement in a while(true) so that it will keep on printing forever instead of simply printing once.

Add this at the very end of your script:

`win.mainloop()`